# CSS Drop Multi Down Menu

Tags: css, menu

I am having some trouble regarding this CSS menu, for trying to make it multi-level drop down.

> From Menu=>Submenu into Menu=>Submenu=>Submenu=>Submenu

How can I do that ?
What is wrong in the code, as it will NOT show the submenu, submenu's !

For full testing it you just need it to copy+paste it to

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-hide-dropdown-on-mouse-hover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
 #contact-links {
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact-links a {
    color: #4C9FEB;
}
#contact-links a:hover {
    color: #3D85C6;
}
#my-links {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#my-links a {
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#my-links a:first-child {
    border-width: 0;
}
#menu-container {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f6f6f6, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#f6f6f6, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#e9eaea',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
    clear: both;
    height: 46px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
#neat-menu {
    float: left;
}
#neat-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#neat-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#neat-menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#neat-menu ul li a {
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset, 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
    border-color: #D1D1D1;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 11px 15px 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#neat-menu ul li a:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#efefef, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#efefef, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#efefef, #e9eaea) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#e9eaea',GradientType=0 );
}
#neat-menu > ul > li.active > a {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55A6F1', endColorstr='#3F96E5',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2D81CC;
    border-top: 1px solid #4791D6;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset, 1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#neat-menu > ul > li.active > a:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#499FEE, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#499FEE, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#499FEE, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#499FEE', endColorstr='#3F96E5',GradientType=0 );
}
#neat-menu > ul > li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#neat-menu ul ul {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#F7F7F7, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F7F7F7', endColorstr='#F4F4F4',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
#neat-menu ul li:hover ul  {
    margin-top: 0\2;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
#neat-menu ul ul a {
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    color: #444444;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
#neat-menu ul ul a:hover {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(#55A6F1, #3F96E5) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#55A6F1', endColorstr='#3F96E5',GradientType=0 );
    border-top: 1px solid #4791D6;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset, 1px 0 0 #55A6F1 inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#neat-menu ul ul li:first-child a {
    border-top-width: 0;
}
#menu-search {
    margin:8px 10px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
#menu-search form {
    background: url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NzU9je1udG4/Uw-1tZku4eI/AAAAAAAAGWs/-h4BU1mFTiU/s1600/menu-search.gif") no-repeat scroll 5% 50% transparent;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
}
#menu-search form:hover {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
#menu-search form input {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 26px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu-search form input.placeholder, #menu-search form input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #C4C4C4;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='contact-links'>
    <div id='my-links'>
        <a href='#'>About</a>
        <a href='#'>Contact</a>
                <a href='#'><img height='18px' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-bsoTf8EpVbE/Uw_W2HmlPOI/AAAAAAAAGXQ/RS57fNXl1tE/s1600/facebook-icon.png' title='Facebook' width='18px'/></a>
<a href='#'><img height='18px' src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9OXxCWCilgM/Uw_WNEqUShI/AAAAAAAAGXI/2T6Dc8zVrxA/s1600/twitter.png' title='Twitter' width='18px' /></a>
        <a href='#'><img height='18px' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LQABZjrBgiY/Uw_X4zGqixI/AAAAAAAAGXo/jlR7r1blHso/s1600/google-plus-icon.png' title='Google' width='18px'/></a>
        <a href='#'><img height='18px' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NsPs8DRJfP4/Uw_XnNMAHTI/AAAAAAAAGXg/qC2kA_T-BdY/s1600/rss-icon.png' title='RSS Feed' width='18px'/></a>
    </div>

    <div id='menu-container'>
        <nav id='neat-menu'>
            <ul>
              <li class='active'><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropdown</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 5</a>
                                                <ul>
                                <li><a href='#'>Sub menu !</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Dropdown</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropdown</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Single Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Single Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropdown</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Menu element 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- menu-search form -->
        <div id='menu-search'>
          <form method='get' action='/search'>
                <input autocomplete='off' name='q' placeholder='search...' type='text' value=''/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

   <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it will not display the Sub menu !

So I want to make this for multiple sub pages or sub menus.
From 1 to even 4 for example.
The main question is how to make it multi drop down levels ?
What is wrong in here ?

Any help will be good and appreciated !